# Show Error Page for No Action found using Struts2

Tags: tomcat, redirect, struts2

I want to handle error condition for no action or result present in url or add permenant redirect to some urls.

When user enter some url which does not exist or is migrated then he gets an error

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action 
>   com.zyx.pqr.action.AbcAction$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c95cf377 and result
>   error

Any way in which we can handle page not found in a better way and also track pages which should permanent redirect or something like that.

Well nothing to add in stack trace or console, just wanted to know how global action error and global redirects can be handled.

Comment: please provide the stacktrace or the exception thrown by it

Comment: What about exception handling functionality? http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/exception-handling.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Struts2 version 2.1 there is `Unknown Handlers` stack.

Unknown Handlers are called when an unknown action, result, or method are executed. You need to implement `com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler` interface and add your Unknown Handlers definition to your `struts.xml` file.

See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/unknown-handlers.html.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: "**Unkown** Handlers" copy-paste from the docs. :)

Comment: I tried using it last night.... control comes to the class that implements UnknownHandler, but the return types are ActionConfig & Result. Can you point to example where I can understand how to redirect to action or show error page incase of error?

Comment: @AmolGhotankar: You need to get existing `ActionConfig` or create it.