# Calling a struts2 action on 404 error

Tags: java, struts2

I want to be able to run a Struts 2 action when there is no mapped action found.

The reason I need to do this is because my users can have URLs like `www.example.com/someValue`.

`someValue` is a variable and I don't know what the value could be. I want to be able to run a specific action if the page is not found.

Comment: If it should have a value then it might map to some variable and return error result if the value is wrong. Otherwise you just get an invalid mapping because the value is treated as action name and if not such name exists then default action will call if configured.

Comment: Thanks @RomanC. I did tried exactly that by having an action with name="/${keyword}", but it never works and I keep getting an error that there is nothing defined for /abcd. I think struts filter outs the request even before it gets to evaluate /${keyword}

Comment: Try without dollar sign because I think it's not valid syntax for regexes. You should also post the configuration file.

Comment: Look at wildcard actions and regex capture matching

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16293143/1700321.

Comment: `my users can have URLs like www.example.com/someValue` also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23788400/1654265

Comment: Thank you so much @AleksandrM & Andrea. Andrea's suggestion that I was actually looking for and it worked for me. Thank you so much guys!