# How to handle unknown action in struts2?

Tags: struts2, action-mapping

I am using struts2 (struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar) and unable to get the below configuration to work when there is a unknown action is requested.

```
            <global-results>
            <result name="globalError">/jsp/common/error.jsp</result>
            </global-results>

            <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="globalError"/>
            </global-exception-mappings>
```

The browser still shows the raw message :
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [signups] associated with context path [].

I am using the following workaround temporarly (it works)

```
                <action name="*" class="com.action.UknownAction">
                <result name="success">/jsp/common/error.jsp</result>
                </action>
```

Comment: 404 status code is handled by the container, what exactly is not working?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16293143/1700321.